# Nginx redirect using return 301

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need to do permanent redirect from URLs:

```
https://SiteName.com/shop/forklift-tires/XXX/
to
https://SiteName.com/shop/tires/forklift-tires/XXX/
```

or

```
https://SiteName.com/shop/forklift-tires/YYY/
to
https://SiteName.com/shop/tires/forklift-tires/YYY/
```

How could I do it using structure below?

```
location *something* {
        return 301 *something*;
}
```

As I understood from article ["Pitfalls and Common Mistakes"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) it`s best to use **return** instead of **rewrite**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update(the correct answer)**

Further to your comment, try this:

```
location  ~ ^shop/forklift-tires/(.*) {
    return 301  /shop/tires/forklift-tires/$1 ;
}
```

**Previous answer (sorry for misunderstood the question)**

Create another server directive like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name Sitename.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

All traffic for http://SiteName.com/* will be redirected to https://SiteName.com/*.

Comment: Maybe I explained it not clear enough. I need to redirect from https://SiteName.com/shop/forklift-tires/XXX/
to
https://SiteName.com/shop/-!!!-tires-!!!-/forklift-tires/XXX/ Http and Https issues isn`t relevant to my question.

Comment: I don`t know why but you code somehow is not working. Also it should work only with URLs that have /shop/ directory prior to /forklift-tires/XXX/

Comment: How about change it to `^/shop/forklift-tires/(.*)` and `/shop/tires/forklift-tires/$1`? Sorry that I don't have a test server available now to test it. You will have to try it yourself.

Comment: You are welcome. For the benefit of others, I edit the answer to reflect the correct one.